product of almost surely convergence and convergence in law
I am trying to solve the following question:

Let $\{X_n\},\{Y_n\}$ be random variables such that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent. When we know $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}X$ and $Y_n\to Y$ in law, can we show that $X_nY_n$ converges in law?

I know that "$X_nY_n\to XY$ in law" does not always follow, but in this question, it does not necessarily to show that limit distribution is $XY$, so I am at a loss.
Are there any good idea?
Thank you.

$(X_n,Y_n)$ converges in law, so $f(X_n,Y_n)$ converges in law for any continuous function $f$.

Could you tell me why $(X_n, Y_n)$ converges in law?

Use characteristic functions.

It is true when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but now independence between $X$ and $Y$ is not required.

$(X_n,Y_n)$ need not converge in law to $(X,Y)$ but it does converge in law to something (namely to $(X',Y')$ where $X'$ has the same law as $X$,$Y'$ has the same law as $Y$ and $X',Y'$ are independent.)  That is all you need.

I understood it well. Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.

@lymd Why did you delete your question about Central limit theorem and random index. I was writing an answer for that one.
